# python - how can I convert image to mp4 format

Tags: python, mp4, opencv

I want to take one image and convert it to one frame like it was part of video.
I can do it with the following code:

```
vidWriter = cv2.VideoWriter('output_video.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V'), 30, size)
vidWriter.write(image)
vidWriter.release()
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('output_video.mp4')
success,image_mp4 = vidcap.read()
```

In this code I take one image, create video from this image (video with only one frame) and read the first frame from the created video.
It is working well, but I need to do it a lot of times in a loop so I don't want to create video each time and read this video.

What I'm looking for is some function that can take one image and convert it to the format that it was if it was part of mp4 video, and faster than the above code.

I prefer to do it with cv2 if it possible.

Thanks

Comment: I'm really confused by what you're looking for. If you want images which have gone through video encoding and decoding... just write all your frames to the video then read them back? Or if what you want is a cv2 image buffer, use imdecode?

Comment: I want images which have gone through video encoding and decoding - but every iteration I get only one image and I need that particular image after encode and decode, so I can't write all images into one video at once. If I will create video in each iteration it will take a lot of time. I will try to use imdecode but I almost sure that I will not get the same array as I will get from encode and decode